# Is their a better algorithm for winning a 4*4*4*4 variant of ultimate tic-tac toe?

Tags: algorithms

For rules please refer to https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/ultimate-ttt .I have implemented minimax search with alpha-beta pruning. There is a time limit of 15 seconds.Which algorithms would yield better results?

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  Please edit your question to make it self-contained.  We don't want questions that can only be understood by clicking on an external link.  (If the link stops working, then the question becomes incomprehensible; and we want people to be able to understand what you are asking without clicking on external links.)  What exactly is the game you are trying to play?  What evaluation function are you using?  Also, what do you mean by "better"?  What metric are you using to evaluate solutions?  What approaches have you considered, and why have you rejected them?

Comment: Cross-posted: http://ai.stackexchange.com/q/2875/1794, http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/70942/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: There are 256 possible moves, each with 256 choices down to 1 choice. I doubt minimax will solve this problem unless there is a very quick forced win.